# Setting time in textbox corresponding with clockpicker

Tags: jquery, clockpicker

I am using the clockpicker from http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/ and I am trying to figure out how to show the time in the textbox (always). I want the time to always be shown as "Now" in the textbox but give the user the ability to change it with the clock window. I have been able to set the 'now' time as default on the clock but I am having two problems.

**First problem**
The clock is not showing if its AM or PM from just using 'Now'

**Second problem** I am unable to display that time in the value of the textbox unless its selected from the clock. I want the time to already be displayed for now. But to allow the user the option to change it with the clock. `Format ex: 08:30 PM`

Any help with this would be greatly appreciated!

http://jsfiddle.net/YkvK9/1714/

```
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>test</label>
    <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-autoclose="true">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
        <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

$('.clockpicker').clockpicker({
   'default': 'now',
   twelvehour: true,
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> There is no such option in the clockpicker to set the input value with
>   current time.

But you can set the input time with current time manually after the clockpicker. Try the below approch.

```js
$('.clockpicker').clockpicker({
  'default': DisplayCurrentTime(),
  twelvehour: true,
}).find('input').val(DisplayCurrentTime())

function DisplayCurrentTime() {
  var date = new Date();
  var hours = date.getHours() > 12 ? date.getHours() - 12 : date.getHours();
  var am_pm = date.getHours() >= 12 ? "PM" : "AM";
  hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
  var minutes = date.getMinutes() < 10 ? "0" + date.getMinutes() : date.getMinutes();
  var seconds = date.getSeconds() < 10 ? "0" + date.getSeconds() : date.getSeconds();
  time = hours + ":" + minutes + ":" + am_pm;
  //time = hours + ":" + minutes + am_pm;
  return time;
};
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.0.0-alpha/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="http://weareoutman.github.io/clockpicker/dist/jquery-clockpicker.min.js"></script>
<div class="col-lg-6">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>test</label>
    <div class="input-group clockpicker" data-autoclose="true">
      <input type="text" class="form-control" value="">
      <span class="input-group-addon">
          <span class="fa fa-clock-o"></span>
      </span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here SlotFrom is the id of textbox. I use following code but it does not read the value at controller side. 
Please give correct solution.

I write following in js

```
<script>
var Dt = new Date();
$('#SlotFrom').clockpicker({autoclose: true,twelvehour: true}).val(moment(Dt.getTime()).format("HH:mm A"));
```